# During hiring have to repeat test for a third time after passing it twice, what for?

Tags: hiring-process, test

I applied for a job.
During the application process, I was asking to accomplish an engineering test. I passed the test. Eventually I was offered the position but the HR was a bit unprofessional and the offer came quite late when I had already accepted another offer.

Around few months latter my other offer did not work so well so I reapplied to the same position I was offered few months before. The HR department told me I do not need to go through all steps but I would need to take the engineering test again. I asked for a waiver. They said no. So I took the test and passed it. Eventually I was offered the position a second time. The salary was below my expectations so I refused it.

Few months latter, and even if it might seem odd to some of you guys, I reconsidered the position and applied to it for a third time. They told me the position is available and they would like to offer it to me. However, they claim I have to go for a third time through the engineering test. I have asked them if they could waive it since I have already passed the test twice.

Question: What does it bring to their recruiting process to make a candidate take the same test three times versus twice in a period of less than a year? When usually the people they hire are passing this test only once.

Comment: Question: why does someone apply for the same job twice, turn it down then apply again? Would the company really be interested in that prospective employee? Would they think the employee will stay?

Comment: Perhaps they are hoping 3rd time lucky - that you will go away...

Comment: @Joe I did not turn down the offer twice. First time they turned it down saying the position is not any more available at the very end of the recruiting process. Few weeks later they pinged me offering it but I had accepted another offer. The second time I turned it down because the salary offered (only revealed at the very end) was significantly below my expectation. So it has nothing to do with being serious. The salary just did not match.

Comment: Why is this engineering test a sticking point for you? Does retaking it bother you that much?

Comment: The employer is just disorganized.

Comment: Ask what your potential salary range would be for the position.  Why are you not countering their offers instead of declining them?  It doesn’t sound like you really want to work there.

Answer (score 9):

**My question is: why on earth would you oppose this?**

I mean, let's take it for granted that you want this job, and that all of this makes sense.

So why on earth wouldn't you want to take the test for the third time?  At this point, you should be able to *blow that test out of the water!*  I mean, heck, if I was interviewing at a software firm for the third time, and knew everything they were going to ask me, I'd have amazing answers to every one of their questions!  First time they ask me about Docker, I'd say "Sorry, that's more of a DevOps thing that I'm not familiar with."  Third time?  "Funny you ask - I was actually building a Docker Container just yesterday to hol..."

Sure, it might take a bit of time.  But considering that it's probably measured in 'hours', and it could possibly give you a great boost to the interview/bargaining... why wouldn't you jump at getting to take it again?

Comment: Because they change the questions every time, so taking it again meaning having to make an appointment again, passing all the stress, reserve a day off for the test, etc etc. In summary a waste of resources provided that I've done it already twice.

Answer (score 6):

> What does it bring to their recruiting process to make a candidate take the same test three times versus twice in a period of less than a year?

It could be a corporate requirement to have all candidates take a coding test. Each time you reapply, you become a new candidate. Side note: some companies also enforce that you cannot apply to the same position until a certain amount of time has passed (e.g. 6 months) to prevent candidates from gaming the test.

Your situation is not a common occurrence. Most candidates don't reapply for the position after rejecting the position when the salary offered was too low. You would try to negotiate the salary and then take or leave the offer.

Answer (score -3):

I have no idea dude, why don't you ask them? If they don't tell you, then you can I suppose refuse the job on principle.

If it's the same test, don't you have the answers somewhere? Why is it even a bother to take the same test that you've already passed twice a third time?